# Upgrade Now Button does not show when upgrading to 4.6.9

Tags: upgrade

I usually run the upgrade process for CiviCRM and it usually works well. On 4.6.9 I noticed that the upgrade now button for [step 11 in the upgrade documentation](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7#UpgradingCiviCRMforDrupal7-11.RuntheUpgradescript) does not show. It says Upgrade CiviCRM to version 4.6.9 but no upgrade button shows. I did manage to upgrade on a non-ssl site but with the sites that have SSL there seems to be problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the verify SSL certs and Force SSL certs before doing the upgrade (even if your site is on SSL) then the upgrade works fine.

So in the upgrade process before turning of CiviCRM additional modules disable the two fields of Verify SSL certs and Force SSL certs. You can find the settings under /civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1

Remember to turn them back on.

Cheers.